# Difference between C-Index and Spearman correlation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

Suppose I have a list that reflects the priority of web pages for recrawling:

```
l1 = [3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Now, I have tried to estimate the priorities with two different approaches and have obtained two lists:

```
l2 = [4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1]
l3 = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

I can use the Spearman correlation or C-Index to know which of l2 or l3 better estimates the l1. My question is that which metric is better? Spearman or C-Index? What is their difference in my case?

Comment: Better for what purpose?  I don't think the question is answerable in its current form - unless you have specific requirements or criteria or a particular situation, "better" is often a matter of opinion.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4260366/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144263/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).